# Apache Axis2 Webservice in regular shared hosting service

Tags: web-services, apache, apache-axis

I developed a webservice in java with Axis2, and now I need to put it online.
In order to do it I signed a shared hosting service, but as I am not familiar with this kind o stuff, I don´t really know how to do it.
It´s a regular shared hosting service, is runs on Apache Tomcat, but I only have access to my home folder, public_html this kinda stuff. 
Can I run my webservice by deploying it and putting it into public_html?
Do I have to deploy it in some way as to add Axis2 files to it, to make it work?

Any help will be much appreciated,

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to deploy .war files. In this case you have to use the Axis2 .war distribution and deploy it in your service hosting environment.

Normally you are given public_html folders in the hosting environments created by appche httpd where you can only deploy html pages. You need to clarify this with your service hosting provider.

You can use WSO2 Stratos live[1] for this kind of purposes. This article[2] describes how to deploy the axis2.war in stratos live.

In fact WSO2 application server[3] is specially written to deploy axis2 artifacts. So even without deploying axis2.war you can directly upload your service as well.

[1] https://stratoslive.wso2.com/home/index.html

[2] http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/run-apache-axis2-webapp-wso2-cloud-0

[3] https://appserver.stratoslive.wso2.com/home/index.html